# How do I match repeated characters?

Tags: ruby

How do I find repeated characters using a regular expression?

If I have `aaabbab`, I would like to match only characters which have three repetitions:

```
aaa
```

Comment: Not enough information to know what you're asking.  Do you mean that you want to find all substrings of a string that consist of repeated characters?  Or at least 3 repeated characters?  Or the first repeated substring?  Or the maximum?

Comment: I want to find does any of the characters in a string repeated exactly or greater than 3 times
EX: "abbbcaa" => needs to match only "bbb"

Comment: what about "abbbcaaa": should it only match "bbb" or "aaa" too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `string.scan(/((.)\2{2,})/).map(&:first)`, where `string` is your string of characters.

The way this works is that it looks for any character and captures it (the dot), then matches repeats of that character (the `\2` backreference) 2 or more times (the `{2,}` range means "anywhere between 2 and infinity times"). Scan will return an array of arrays, so we map the first matches out of it to get the desired results.

Comment: In my case, I had to find the exact number of repetitions so changed `{2,}` with `{5}` to match the exact `6` repetitions.